# Работа с exe файлом в Qt Creator C++

Tags: c++, qt

Не нашел подходящей информации в интернете, призываю к вашей помощи! К сути:
Написал игру шахматы на С++ в Qt, теперь хочу подключить exe файл - шахматный движок.
Идея в чем: после совершения хода координаты будут преобразовываться в формат "e2e4", сообщение такого формата должно быть написано в stockfish.exe (как раз таки движок, представляет из себя консоль), от него выводится ответное сообщение, в котором мой проект должен найти строчку "bestmove d2d4", и далее я уже реализую ход на доске d2d4, к примеру.

Вопрос, как это вообще реализовать, использовать QFile или QProcess, как правильно считать из exe приложения его вывод?
Спасибо[image: вот пример запущеного exe файла]

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Добавляйте тесктовую информацию в виде текстовых блоков. Исправить можно нажать на [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1333759/edit) внизу вопроса

Comment: Как написано https://stockfishchess.org/download/ [Windows] `The Stockfish chess engine is a command line program`, значит `QProcess` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как и было сказано вам нужно использовать QProcess, добавив обработку некоторых сигналов.

Предполагаем что на форме лежит plainTextEdit (сюда будем писать вывод программы), lineEdit (сюда будете вбивать команды) и pushButton (кнопка отправки команды).

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QString p, QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    // На форме лежат:
    // QPlainTextEdit* plainTextEdit
    // QLineEdit* lineEdit
    // QPushButton* pushButton;
    // QProcess* ac - объявлен в mainwindow.h
    ac=new QProcess(this); // Создаем объект
    connect(ac, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(stdOut())); // привязываем слот стандартного вывода
    connect(ac, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()), this, SLOT(stdOut())); // Возможно и не понадобится, но привяжем и стандартный поток ошибок
    connect(ac, SIGNAL(finished(int)),this,SLOT(acFinished(int))); //привязываем слот к сигналу о завершении программы
    ac->start("cmd.exe",QStringList());   //Запустим программу
    ac->write("chcp 65001\n");  //пишем в стандартный ввод
    ac->waitForBytesWritten();

}
void MainWindow::stdOut()
{
    QByteArray tmp=((QProcess*)sender())->readAllStandardOutput(); //читаем что там навалилось в стандартном выводе
    if(!tmp.trimmed().isEmpty())
        ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(QString::fromUtf8(tmp));
    tmp=((QProcess*)sender())->readAllStandardError(); //читаем что там навалилось в поток ошибок
    if(!tmp.trimmed().isEmpty())
        ui->plainTextEdit->appendHtml(QString("<font color='red'>%1</font>").arg(QString::fromUtf8(tmp)));

}

void MainWindow::acFinished(int exitCode)
{
    ui->plainTextEdit->appendHtml(QString("<b>exec done. exit code=%1</b>").arg(exitCode)); // Выводим сообщение что программа завершена

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ac->write(ui->lineEdit->text().toUtf8().data());  //пишем в стандартный ввод
    ac->write("\n");
    ac->waitForBytesWritten();
}
```

Comment: Сергей, спасибо. Но есть проблемка. При этом подходе невозможно использовать процесс "ас" в слоте stdOut, т.к. он определяет его как неизвестную переменную Может стоит передавать этот процесс как аргумент в слот то есть: void stdOut(&ac), соответственно connect(as, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(stdOut(QProcess&)));
Тогда выдаст ошибку:
Incompatible sender/receiver arguments

Comment: @God добавьте такую строку в начало этого слота  QProcess* ac = qobject_cast<QProcess*>(sender());

Comment: Прошу прощения, надергал из проекта где ac был в mainwindow.h объявлен. В предыдущем комментарии решение этой проблемы.  или см. слот. подправил код.

Comment: Вроде читается, но с записью проблемы, пытаюсь прочитать уже после записи, ничего нового не выводит.
А если пытаюсь добавить метод write() в слот нажатия кнопки, то компилируется, но выдает странную ошибку:
QIODevice::write (QPushButton, "pushButton_2"): device not open
После появления ошибки приложение резко завершается

Comment: После записи в процесс необходимо использовать метод 
void QProcess::closeWriteChannel(), только в этом случае можно записать в процесс желаемую строку.

Если проблем больше не возникнет, закрою вопрос, Спасибо)

Comment: Проблема в том, что сигнал readyReadStandardOutput() испускается только тогда, когда функция, в которой мы открываем и пишем в процесс - заканчивается.

То есть пройдя по отладке я понял, что сначала заканчивается функция, а уже потом начинает выполнение слот stdOut

А использовать функцию или вызвать вручную stdOut() невозможно, ибо программа экстренно закрывается

Comment: обновил код. теперь это полностью рабочий пример работы в cmd. то что у вас не испускаются сигналы говорит только о проблемах в вашем коде (происходит блокирование eventloop). На приведенном примере посмотрите что все работает, закрывайте вопрос и открывайте другой, с проблемой блокировки сигналов