# Взаимодействие с консолью java программы

Tags: python

Требуется написать скрипт который запускает в отдельном потоке программу и может взаимодействовать с её консолью.
Есть сервер minecraft, который запускается через консоль. Я могу запускать его с помощью subprocess, но как вводить комманды в консоль, я так и не разобрался.
[image: Само приложение]

Главный скрипт представляет с собой телеграм бота, с помощью которого я хочу реализовать удалённое управление. Второстепенной задачей является запускать приложение в отдельном потоке, чтобы сам скрипт не останавливался, так как в любой момент времени может поступить команда.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как всегда возможны варианты... можно примерно так

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['cmd','/c','dir'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
  line = proc.stdout.readline()
  if not line:
    break
  print ("test: "+str(line.rstrip()))
```

можно перерисовать [вот это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1333759/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-exe-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2-qt-creator-c/1333816#1333816) с C++Qt на PyQt

Comment: Так вопрос был в том, как взаимодействовать с программой. На сервер может прилететь например команда /stop, и скрипту нужно грубо говоря вписать это в консоль программы с дальнейшей обработкой.

Comment: это тоже возможно см. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363853/reading-writing-to-a-popen-subprocess хотя я бы переписал пример с QProcess на pyqt